# Bootstrap date and time picker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, datetimepicker

Suggest me any JavaScript to pick the  date and time 
.

NOTE: I want to use only  one file for date and time picking.

I already see this:

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

and

http://jdewit.github.com/bootstrap-timepicker/index.html

Comment: If this question is "not constructive", why does it have twenty upvotes and thirty stars? Certainly seems as though people want to ask the same question and find the answer below useful.

Comment: @aidan Questions asking for library recommendations without a well-specified problem to solve tend not to be liked around here. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Comment: @MarkAmery yeah, I'm aware of the rules. I guess this isn't the place to debate it, but suffice to say, I disagree with such a hard-line interpretation of the "rule".

Comment: @aidan: What I find not constructive about this "question" is that it's not a question. It's an order.

Comment: @EricDuminil Agreed. It could have been phrased better. But let's look past that and look at the value this question and it's answer are bringing the community. Clearly it's net positive?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

If you are still interested in a javascript api to select both date and time data, have a look at these projects which are forks of bootstrap datepicker:

- [Bootstrap Datetime Picker 1](http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)
- [Bootstrap Datetime Picker 2](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

The first fork is a big refactor on the parsing/formatting codebase and besides providing all views to select date/time using mouse/touch, it also has a mask option (by default) which lets the user to quickly type the date/time based on a pre-specified format.

Comment: For bootstrap 3 I use http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: I use tempusdominus for Bootstrap 4. https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/

Comment: Bootstrap 5 anyone?