# Bootstrap datepicker 2.0 display calender in monthly view

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, monthcalendar

Is there any option for User to select only month, instead of date in Bootstrap datepicker. I am trying to do is allow users pick months and years only.

```js
 $('.date').each(function() {
     var datepickerComponent = $(this).datepicker({
        language: 'en',
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        viewMode: "months", 
        minViewMode: "months"
      }).on('changeDate', function() {
        $(datepickerComponent).datepicker('hide');
      });
  });
```

I tried all option mentioned in this below link. But I didn't get expected behaviour.

Link to other question:

[Bootstrap Datepicker - Months and Years Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974394/bootstrap-datepicker-months-and-years-only)

Please help me.

Comment: why not showing a dropdown from 1 till 12 for selecting months?

Comment: User/client can easily change month/year using this bootstrap and validation option are available( for 'FROM' and 'TO' date).

Comment: Your code is working fine to select month-year, what error are you getting?

Comment: @Srini Did you Ctrl+F5 to refresh the browser? Just try it out.

Comment: No., still I am getting calendar view in DayView only. It is, user can view/able to select day of month. But I didn't want that.

Comment: With the code above, I get month view and not day view http://jsfiddle.net/qdqzyare/2/

Comment: ok.,,I am using bootstrap v2.0.0.Thank you..,I will check with latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap provides DateTimePicker also. It resolves my problem. We have lots of options in DateTimePicker.

    `$(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM-yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
            pickTime: false,
            viewMode: 'months',
            minViewMode: 'months'
        });`

For more information please go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985495/bootstrap-date-and-time-picker)