# ASP .NET MVC 5 Date and time picker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

In my ASP .NET MVC 5 app, I have a model class:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I would like to have a date and time picker to be able to set event's date and time in its Date property.

Currently I'm allowing to edit `Date` using `@Html.JQueryUI().DatepickerFor(model => model.Date)` in my view, however this only provides me with date picker, there is no hour/minutes to choose.

I've looked through forums and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985495/bootstrap-date-and-time-picker) post and I would really like to make a use of [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), but I cannot manage to install and use it properly.

I installed NuGet package `Bootstrap.DateTimePicker` and tried to put the sample code from [here](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) directly into my view:

```
    <div class="well">
    <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
        <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
        <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
            </i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      language: 'pt-BR'
    });
  });
</script>
```

but it only shows an empty blank textbox, date/datetime picker does not appear at all. I don't even know how to bind this potential DateTimePicker to my model's property Date.

I suppose I forgot about something, maybe including some scripts somewhere?
I've looked through the [manual](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and net, but I cannot make it working...

In browser console i have:

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 
>   jquery-ui-1.11.4.js:14  jquery-ui-1.11.4.js:6
>   ReferenceError: $ is not defined Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript
>   requires jQuery

Edit:
I'm also attaching the contents of my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
          href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/jquery-ui.css"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>



    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - NOMU</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

    @*style for vertical tabs*@
    <style>
        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav {
            padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em;
            float: left;
            width: 12em;
        }

        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {
            clear: left;
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
            border-right-width: 0 !important;
            margin: 0 -1px .2em 0;
        }

        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
            display: block;
        }

        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
            padding-bottom: 0;
            padding-right: .1em;
            border-right-width: 1px;
            border-right-width: 1px;
        }

        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel {
            padding: 1em;
            float: right;
            width: 40em;
        }
    </style>




    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


        <script src="~/Scripts/globalize/globalize.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.@(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name).js"></script>
        <script>
            $.validator.methods.number = function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) ||
                    !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                Globalize.culture('@(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)');
            });
        </script>
        <script>
            jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
                range: function(value, element, param) {
                    //Use the Globalization plugin to parse the value
                    var val = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
                    return this.optional(element) || (
                        val >= param[0] && val <= param[1]);
                }
            });
            $.validator.methods.date = function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) ||
                    Globalize.parseDate(value) ||
                    Globalize.parseDate(value, "yyyy-MM-dd");
            }
        </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
        language: 'pt-BR'
      });

        </script>


    }

</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("HOME", "Index", "Home", new {area = ""}, new {@class = "navbar-brand"})
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Members", "Index", "Members")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Addresses", "Index", "Addresses")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Departments", "Index", "Departments")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Events", "Index", "Events")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Payments", "Index", "Payments")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr/>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Site Title</p>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")



@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT 2015-12-05:**

Thank you for trying to help, but I still cannot find the solution... I will try to provide as many details as possible.

Surely I'm integrating this into my solution bad, as if I create sample HTML file with the HTML code as @coderealm proposed below it of course works.

Ok, so without any datetime picker my view looks that way:
[image]

Here is the HTML code this view produces:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive-3.0.0.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>

    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



    <style type="text/css">
        ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>




    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/jquery-ui.css"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>


    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create - Event</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



    <style>
        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav {
            padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em;
            float: left;
            width: 12em;
        }

        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {
            clear: left;
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
            border-right-width: 0 !important;
            margin: 0 -1px .2em 0;
        }

        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
            display: block;
        }

        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
            padding-bottom: 0;
            padding-right: .1em;
            border-right-width: 1px;
            border-right-width: 1px;
        }

        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel {
            padding: 1em;
            float: right;
            width: 40em;
        }
    </style>







</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">HOME</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/Members">Members</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Addresses">Addresses</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Departments">Departments</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Events">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Payments">Payments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Messages/Create">Send message</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Administration <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Users & Roles</li>
                            <li><a href="/Account/Register">Create new user</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Roles">Manage roles</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

            </ul>




<style type="text/css">
    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }
</style>



<form action="/Account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="esfmyOwwGOynXzXzmRDd8FnKUZX5pNVDXdpcZwtBEq4y5j1d9fPS-0ce2pemBsSi3Yp4l8NOWs5hXvgxQpQP3t-n-9V3P1SuvEurk2RCd9WJO9gilnBwQqgSll4F2WsGHR3NMNKFkrdZD0uy8lJQdw2" />    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Hello user@gmail.com <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Account</li>
                <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Manage">Manage</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">





<h2>Create</h2>

<form action="/Events/Create" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="ChQ9Bowi5lfzRdqywpBOd6DW8xX7EDm19zq0IL3f_MqTAjOXPlL6fiK-pLbdDeonHzsCQfWOEQ7lU3j-t1lCBpqGL7rOu1vlapqJpM2zUbcHGicp4QpaIvxrQpOihUlVy9qypWEHhuRHEHJ-Q--rkw2" />    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Event</h4>
        <hr />



        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Name">Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Date">Date</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">

                <input data-jqui-dpicker-dateformat="yy-mm-dd" data-jqui-type="datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date must be a date." id="Date" name="Date" type="text" value="" />

                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Date" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>         

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Place">Place</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Place" name="Place" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Place" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Mandatory">Mandatory</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input class="check-box" id="Mandatory" name="Mandatory" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Mandatory" type="hidden" value="false" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Mandatory" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>






<div>
    <a href="/Events">Back to List</a>
</div>


    <hr/>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2015 - Title</p>
    </footer>
</div>






<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Firefox","requestId":"841bbc2758464834b8d3ce225ba16e58"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:2142/e8ea71ac5d3f49bd91e335052d0353be/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

My field for `Date` currently uses jquery DatePicker (in the view I just do `@Html.JQueryUI().DatepickerFor(model => model.Date)` to make use of it) and it displays simple jquery calendar fine, but as I mentioned it's not possible to choose hours. So I decided to use abovementioned [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), so I installed it from NuGet and:

1. According to what @coderealm suggested, I put the `<head>` part of the sample code into my `_Layout.cshtml` file to be common within all views. I put it just before the end of `<head>` section: [here](http://pastebin.com/xmhY0Tkg) (sorry for PasteBin, this message is too long already).

And just after pasting this code there when I reload my View it changes its look (it's actually enough to paste only `<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` in `_Layout.csthml` file for this to happen):
[image]

As you can see, text fields are like smaller, titles are not bold now. BTW, my old jquery Datepicker still works fine at this moment, but I suppose it's not OK that the view of these textboxes and generally the layout is changed. The HTML produced by the above view has now changed for the following one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive-3.0.0.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>

    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



    <style type="text/css">
        ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>




    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/jquery-ui.css"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>


    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create - Event</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



    <style>
        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav {
            padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em;
            float: left;
            width: 12em;
        }

        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {
            clear: left;
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
            border-right-width: 0 !important;
            margin: 0 -1px .2em 0;
        }

        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
            display: block;
        }

        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
            padding-bottom: 0;
            padding-right: .1em;
            border-right-width: 1px;
            border-right-width: 1px;
        }

        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel {
            padding: 1em;
            float: right;
            width: 40em;
        }
    </style>





   <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
          href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">HOME</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/Members">Members</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Addresses">Addresses</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Departments">Departments</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Events">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Payments">Payments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Messages/Create">Send message</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Administration <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Users & Roles</li>
                            <li><a href="/Account/Register">Create new user</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Roles">Manage roles</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

            </ul>




<style type="text/css">
    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }
</style>



<form action="/Account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="DuIycgdv9rnUap62YqrY4A0imdnNK99uk3sK_LNm8OFv2fj3PKnhDYAp1gr87Cke0r-EDSb2cZGhCoH3x8kcu0bU7GqCQQlHEvntgaRNsqU8rpRcJHzVY40LTk-S56i3OfWeJQGqsc7azegYEodNmw2" />    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Hello test@gmail.com <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Account</li>
                <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Manage">Manage</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">





<h2>Create</h2>

<form action="/Events/Create" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="a-m23Z2lGhcnMvAvJit74BPW2oqJFPsP9qQ4KjUASZobUsiYp5Q48K-rCR7ZjGm4GPD0dihBjBRuMmAVUiIM9qOjojMLFIQ2_X2i0EtgvGUY3OKVJ9BB_wzb8tcTTiN4wxURNAK1M2VDPKjLkjEDig2" />    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Event</h4>
        <hr />



        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Name">Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Date">Date</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">

                <input data-jqui-dpicker-dateformat="yy-mm-dd" data-jqui-type="datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date must be a date." id="Date" name="Date" type="text" value="" />

                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Date" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>         

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Place">Place</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Place" name="Place" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Place" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Mandatory">Mandatory</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input class="check-box" id="Mandatory" name="Mandatory" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Mandatory" type="hidden" value="false" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Mandatory" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>






<div>
    <a href="/Events">Back to List</a>
</div>


    <hr/>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2015 - Title</p>
    </footer>
</div>






<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Firefox","requestId":"3ca3ab4389224867b6caa3f9435eeb1d"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:2142/e8ea71ac5d3f49bd91e335052d0353be/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

2. If I now put the `<body>`'s part of the sample HTML code provided by @coderealm into my `Create.cshtml` view file (I put it just before the last `div` element which adds `ActionLink` to go back to the `Index.cshtml` within the same controller): [here](http://pastebin.com/1ftab68J)

It adds the new DateTimePicker, however after choosing the day and time it is stuck in this state:

[image]

and I'm not able to close this DatetimePicker, when I click somewhere it does not disappear. The HTML code it produced this time is (sorry I need to put this on PasteBin, as the message's length is exceeded): [here](http://pastebin.com/LqHn91dA).

I hope someone will now be able to help me, as it's already driving me crazy... I'm not originally web developer, so probably I messed something up within my views, maybe I load scripts not properly or something...

Once more - thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Make sure you're leveraging the developer console for your browser which might be outputting errors that would be helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: The errors I get opening this view in developer console:
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
<anonymous> jquery-ui-1.11.4.js:14
<anonymous> jquery-ui-1.11.4.js:6
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Comment: @ikS11 show your script section

Comment: @ikS11 Okay, that error is pretty self explanatory. When the bootstrap.js script loaded, jquery.js was not available. This could happen if jquery isn't loaded first.

Comment: This is my scripts section in _Layout.cshtml -> http://pastebin.com/PvG94B1w

Comment: Ok, maybe I will show all my _Layout.cshtml fiile, as probably something is wrong there -> http://pastebin.com/fe5B4vfA

Comment: Edit relevant code into your question (the edit link is under the tag list), rather than posting a link to pastebin.

Comment: So there is actually still no answer... Maybe someone knows another better approaches to display date and time in MVC views?

Comment: I've modified my question with the sample code I used to try, can you take a look once more? The new part starts with "EDIT 2015-12-05".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

Regarding my original issue I still don't know what was happening it was not working, however I found another way :).

I decided to make a use of [this JQueryUI DateTimePicker addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

All you need to do to make it working (in my case with my `Date` field):

1. You need jQuery and jQueryUI installed within your project (if you are already using jQueryUI.Datepicker you have these already)
2. Now it's the time to install jQueryUI datetimepicker addon, you have two possibilities:

   A) Install it manually:

   - from [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) website download .js and .css file (links on the given page under `Download` section)
   - add the `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js` file into your solution's `Scripts` folder
   - Add the  `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css` into your solution's `Content` folder

   B) Install using NuGet (I prefer this method):

   - refer to [addon's NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/) and install it using Package Manager Console
3. In your `_Layout.cshtml` add:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { $('#selectedDateTime').datetimepicker(); });
</script>
```

and:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="/Content/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" />
```

4. Finally, in your view use it that way:

```html
<input type="text" id="selectedDateTime" name="Date"/>
```

This will provide you with that beautiful DateTimePicker:

[image]

Remember that this `name` parameter for `input` field is the name of the parameter which will be posted while you submit your form.

I hope it helps someone in the future ;).

Thank you for all your time :).

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this in a notepad editor and save it on disk as, name the file test.html. Now open test.html is a web browser and it works. Now follow this file to the later and implement in your solution

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
         href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
          <input type="text"></input>
          <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
            language: 'pt-BR'
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    <html>
```

Comment: I've put these in my scripts section, but it's still not working.

Comment: Please check in your output (page source) that jQuery is loaded before bootstrap and that you include it only once. You should also keep an eye on your versions - In your question you posted links to bootstrap 3, but @coderealm has linked bootstrap 2.2 - This may can cause (strange) issues.

Comment: The sources are CDN , so you have to have internet connectivity on your development machine or download the files and add to you solution

Comment: I followed the code you provided and datetimepicker appeared! However now I have some other strange issues, this picker does cannot be closed (meaning wrapped after choosing the date) and I found that when I have " @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")" in my _Layout.cshtml it does not work, but when I comment this out it works perfectly fine, so probably some of my css files or scripts inside css folder are causing the issue...

Comment: Actually the "/Content/bootstrap.css" file is causing the issues. While this file is rendered, it causes layout to behave unexpectedly. If I comment rendering this one, everything is fine...

Comment: I am not sure if it is right, but you could try re-ordering the call to the scripts. Sometime before i had some issues like this and remeber someone telling this as a solution..

Comment: I've tried and it did not help. Visibly rendering bootstrap.css makes this issue happen. Maybe there is any easier way to display time picker, not exactly this one I chose ?

Comment: I  believe  you are not integrating with  your  solution  probably  because  it works  outside  your  solution

Comment: I've modified my question with the sample code I used to try, can you take a look now? The new part starts with "EDIT 2015-12-05".